# How can I use uid in flutter to get user information from firebase Realtime database and how to add uid in my user table

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

This is my user table from where I am saving my fields to firebase , how can I add my current user uid in this table.

```
Future<bool> addUser(
    String name,
    String email,
    String numb,
  ) async{
    print('ssssss');
  final Map<String, dynamic> productData={'name': name, ' email': email, 'numb': numb
    };
    print(productData);
}
[How to add uid column in user table and get current user uid][https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW8TB.png]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW8TB.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the UID of user :

```
 FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 User user = _auth.currentUser;
 print(user.uid);
```

Comment: As I am doing this but it is still giving me an error like null id

Answer (score 0):

```
 void saveData() {
   
 Future<bool> addUser(
    String name,
    String email,
    String numb,
  ) async{
    print('ssssss');
  final Map<String, dynamic> productData={'name': name, ' email': email, 'numb': numb
    };
// stored pushed key in variable and print it on console
    DatabaseReference userId = _ref.push();
    print('Pushed Key' + userId.key);
    id = userId.key;
    userId.set(data);
    print(productData);
}
```

Here you will get user pushed key id and also get printed on console.